# Add inside jsx component a variable

Tags: reactjs

I have the next situation in my application:

At the top, i imported `import {Flowersvg, Carsvg, Catsvg} from "../../images"`
I want to make create jsx like this: `<${i}/>`.

Taking into account this logic i want to render it inside map loop:

```js
arr.map(i => {
  return `<${i}/>`
})
```

`arr` contains many values. Depending by this, `i` will render each time a new JSX. So, i want to create a new component inside `map()`. On first render could be `<Carsvg/>`, second could be `<Flowersvg/>`. Doing this i want to avoid creating many `if`.
At the end i want to get the next scenario:

depending by the list items from `arr` i should get one or another jsx component. For example if in `arr` will be `carsvg`, and `i` also will be `carsvg`, i want to render  component, and so on.

 It is possible to render in the same way the jsx?

Comment: You just need to name your component with UpperCase first character and render it `arr.map(Comp => {
  return <Comp/>
})`

Comment: @Shubham Khatri, why did you close my question? My issue is totaly different that you sugested. I want to know how to render the component if in my `arr` could be for example `flower`, the `i` will be `flower`. So depending by `i` i should render one component or another. In my case i will render <Flower/>. That question that you sugest me is toataly different. It just render a list of components.

Comment: Please update your question to include that information. In your original post you did not mention that mapping and your code snippet seemed to suggest that i referred to `Flower`. I will reopen the post. Also include the information on how and where arr is created

Answer (score 0):

You can use this API and dynamically change values

```
React.createElement(
  type,
  [props],
  [...children]
)
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement